# Kafka Consumer taking long time to consume messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using **Spring Kafka** to post message. When I am posting 100 messages to the kafka topic I can see that it is picked up by Kafka consumer with a delay of at least 1 second or even 4 to 5 seconds in some cases. The topic which I am using has 6 partitions and I have kept the concurrency of consumer to 6.

I have used the default properties value for the Kafka consumer. Any idea what may be wrong or which property I can tweak to minimize the lag to 1 to 2 milliseconds? I tried posting 100, 500, 1000, 5000 messages but the lag is still there.

Consumer properties:

- request timeout ms 30 seconds
- heartbeat interval ms 3 seconds
- max poll interval ms 5 minutes
- max poll records 200
- session timeout ms 45 seconds

Consumer class

[image]

Here is my consumer method:

```
@KafkaListener(groupid = AlertsKafkaConfig.GROUP_ID_JSON, topics = TopicNameConstants.Webhook_doc_process_topic_name, containerFacotry = KafkaTopicConstans.WEBHOOK_PROCESS_TOPIC_CONF)
Public void receiveProcessPricessingMessage(@Payload String kafkajsonstring, @Header(KafkaHeaders RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) String timestamp, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) String offset) throws JsonProcessingException {

    try {
        long startime = System.currenttimemillis();
        RequestFactory.appendKafkaId(offset);
        long endtime = System.currenttimemillis();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        WebhookProcessingCommand eventprocessingcommand = gson.fromJson(kafkajsonstring, WebhookProcessingCommand.class);

        BaseAbstractEventHandler eventprocessinghandler = eventhandlerfactory.getEventhandlerInstance(EventHandler.WEBHOOK_JSON_EVENT_HANDLER.getHandlerName());
        eventprocessinghandler.processEvent(eventprocessingcommand);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.fullStackTrace(e));

    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code where you are consuming messages.

Comment: It's not possible to transfer data from the producer to any consumer on the order of 1-2 milliseconds.

Comment: What can be the minimum lag?As the requirement is to process each message within 100ms

Comment: @Mar-Z Have attached the code for consumer class consuming the messages

Comment: Code should be pasted as formatted text. Not a picture. I can see one problem already. Will post the answer after code available as text.

Comment: @Mar-Z Added the code as text.

Comment: Lag isn't counted in time in Kafka, only offsets. Regardless, `new Gosn()` doesn't compile, does it? In any case, Kafka and Spring include Jackson... You should not use Gson or create a brand new parser _for every Kafka message_

Comment: Docs on using Json https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#json-serde

Comment: @OneCricketeer that was a typo ,corrected the spell error.I am using splunk log to see the time when producer sends the message and the time message gets consumed I.e. it comes to the above method which I have added.That shows a lag of 500ms 1second or sometimes even more

Comment: As the answer below says, you shouldn't construct Gson parser. It's not needed with Spring. Also `currenttimemillis` doesn't compile either. Please show your actual code as-is, and not images of it. Also loggers should be written like `LOGGER.info("text {}" data);` not `("text " + data)` as concatenation will always pre-compute a string before passed into the log function

Comment: @OneCricketeer those are typo error .I cannot copy the code from my machine to here as it is official.So i manually wrote it.One simple question if I post a message to kafka topic how much time in milliseconds it takes to reach the consumer method defined above?For me it takes 200ms or more..This is the lag I want to minimize.Any idea how can I tune that so that it reaches my consumer method at less than 10 milliseconds.

Comment: 1) Did you change what I suggested yet, or not? Changing your json library and logger will help with speed 2) Kafka isn't a good use case for that. Producer flushes are blocking calls. The broker is still required to write batches to disk before consumer can see data... That's not going to happen in less than 10ms... Use point-to-point protocols like gRPC if you need fast transfers of binary data, or brokers like ZeroMQ

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the input.Ya I did change as told .speed of processing has increased.But the only problem was lag which I highlighted which you told is not possible in kafka.

Comment: There are other OS, network and hardware changes you can do, like run Kafka on XFS formatted drives, increase network buffers, make sure you're running latest versions of server and clients, don't overload your requests with plaintext formats like JSON (instead of binary like Avro or Protobuf) or encryption/externalized authentication, use Java 17, increase server heap space, etc... https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

With your current settings Kafka consumer runs synchronously and reads messages one by one in a single thread. This could be fine if the listener method would run fast enough to be ready to pickup the next message at time. It is definitely not the case with the code provided. This is the main cause of the gap you see in the logs. The processing of each message just takes to long.

The cardinal sinn is to construct a new class inside of the handler method. It should be done only once. Preferably as a singleton for the whole application. Spring can help here with a configuration bean and dependency injection.

I'm not aware of classes RequesterFactory (RequestFactory?). Maybe they also take some time? And the JSON deserialization of the payload. And yet another place where an instance of an event handler will be produced dynamically in every call.

Try to refactor the code and check the results. If you need to be even faster then you can optimize the concurrency of the consumers. Now you have only one per partition.

Comment: Hi @Mar-Z now the concurrency is set as 6.If I increase the concurrency the number of consumer threads will increase creating a bottleneck .As we have multiple Kafka consumers in our application each processing different type of traffic so in totality the number of threads may increase drastically. Also if concurrency is increased the processing will be asynchronous right? One more point to note even if I post 1 message to topic it comes to the consumer method with 500ms or 1 seconds lag

Comment: Also the entire processing of the consumer method for each message  provided takes around 60-70 ms

Comment: @Barun Spring concurrency setting has nothing to with processing data from one Kafka partition, or offset.